# ProxyJump not running ForceCommand defined in sshd_config

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

On a bastion host, I have a shell_session_recording.sh script which uses the script command to record ssh session on bastion host and all interactive sessions ie all remote session after connecting to the bastion. (2 steps connections works fine).

I now added a config file in my .ssh to use ProxyJump. But when connection made to the remote servers, the session is not recorded.

shell_session_recording.sh

```
  # The format of log files is /var/log/bastion/YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS_user
  LOG_FILE="`date --date="today" "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`_`whoami`"
  LOG_DIR="/var/log/bastion/"

  # Print a welcome message
  echo ""
  echo "NOTE: This SSH session will be recorded"
  echo "AUDIT KEY: $LOG_FILE"
  echo ""
  SUFFIX=`mktemp -u _XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

  # Wrap an interactive shell into "script" to record the SSH session
  script -qf --timing=$LOG_DIR$LOG_FILE$SUFFIX.time $LOG_DIR$LOG_FILE$SUFFIX.data --command=/bin/bash
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
ForceCommand /usr/bin/bastion/shell_session_recording.sh
```

~/.ssh/config

```
Host webserver
  Hostname 10.10.11.12
  User john
  ProxyJump john@10.10.10.10
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProxyJump` does not run a ForceCommand because it does not run *any* command at all – it does not open any interactive shell session, only a TCP tunnel (similar to the `-L` or `-W` options).

The only thing visible to the bastion host is an **encrypted** SSH session between the client and the destination host.